# Concise way to access a dictionary value when the key is unknown

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of big dictionaries with keys that are strings of text.  Each key value pair has an identical format.  I frequently end up needing to print out one of the values to verify the structure (*which* key:value pair doesn't matter) using the following:

```
my_dict[list(my_dict.keys())[ARBITRARY INDEX]]
```

I feel like there has to be a more eloquent way to do this, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by arbitrary, exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I edited the title. Arbitrary in the sense of "any", i.e. it does not matter which value.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I originally avoided the word arbitrary because similar questions for that used it in the sense of "a given value that can change".  I wanted to convey "a value whose actual value is unknown".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3 (where `dict.values` does not return a full fledged list), you can get an arbitrary value in a memory efficient way with

```
next(iter(d.values()))
```

If there's a chance that the dictionary might have no values, wrap it in a helper function that catches the `StopIteration`, i.e.:

```
def get_arb_value(dic):
    try:
        return next(iter(dic.values()))
    except StopIteration:
        # do whatever you like
```

The Python 2 equivalent of `next(iter(dic.values()))` would be `next(dic.itervalues())`.

Comment: You don't need to wrap it in a `try-except` since `next` takes a default value: e.g. `next(iter([]), None)`

Comment: Sure, I just don't know what OP wants to happen in that case, you can put more logic in the `except` block than just returning something.

Comment: @timgeb, this was purely for exploratory purposes, so the unwrapped version is perfect.  It should never be used on an empty dictionary, but if it is, knowing that it is `None` is perfect.

Comment: This essentially re-implements dic.popitem().

Comment: @TerryJanReedy no, not at all. `popitem` removes a key-value pair.

Comment: Okay. I need help in this part. I have a dictionary `dic={a : (None ,None , 2 , 6) , ...}`  Now. I want to perform an operation such that that I give  any two elements of the tuple (the value)  and I get the key of that value of that entire tuple.

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson that warrants its own question. Make sure to include your attempt / research when posting it.

Comment: @timgeb , I cannot ask questions.  I got an ip ban for asking poor questions.  The only thing I can do is comment and upvote

Answer (score 4):

You could simply do this:

```
list(d.values())[0]
```

In other words, take all the values, convert to a list, take the first one.

Comment: This seems so obvious now that I read it.  There's really no reason to touch the keys at all.

Comment: timgeb's solution would probably be better, especially with a large dictionary.